# After changing password, old password is still valid for EWS API

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

After changing the password for a particular user in O365, the old password of that user is still valid( and valid for pretty long time) when making EWS api calls but the old password does not work when trying to connect to other O365 services from powershell and owa portal.

Is this by design?

Comment: How long have you seen this dual behavior?  Maybe an overnight CRON job has to run before the new password gets synched everywhere?

Comment: I came to notice this only yesterday as i was implementing a password synchronization feature. If it takes so long then is not this an issue from security perspective?

Comment: If you use a OAuth token or similar, that could be valid even after changing the password.